# Changing plot scaling in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to generate a 2D plot with the following Octave code:

```
x_axis = [0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 34000, 36000, 38000, 40000, 42000, 44000, 46000, 48000, 50000, 55000];
y_axis = [0.0, 1.1362139943230667, 3.011725480219328, 4.545131757387976, 5.645494339268811, 6.341632245863471, 7.55485783191341, 9.698082845719652, 9.81715090204222, 8.629366029821481, 7.01446673437068, 5.947197763974984, 5.318901760924856, 4.383110951158656, 3.829896079165435, 3.1783656030517826, 2.547173908996705, 2.0871037643293615, 1.6803970681818023, 1.3409807153873572, 1.0809200851333154, 0.8306496482769604, 0.7009640582695764, 0.565624976300148, 0.4724802489742704, 0.30894265221854744, 2.333168554726147];

plot(x_axis, y_axis, '-o');
axis([0 55000 0 12], "tic[xy]");

set(gca, 'xtick', 0:52000:2000)
set(gca, 'xticklabel', {'0', '2000', '4000', '6000', '8000', '10000', '12000', '14000', '16000', '18000', '20000', '22000', '24000', '26000', '28000', '30000', '32000', '34000', '36000', '38000', '40000', '42000', '44000', '46000', '48000', '50000', '55000'})
```

I have the y-axis scaled the way I want it, but I want there to be ticks on the x-axis corresponding to each x-value that I'm graphing. Octave seems to be forcing the graph to have a square aspect ratio when I'd actually like for the x-axis to be elongated compared to the y-axis. How can I force Octave to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try with `pbaspect`, which allows you to set the proportion when displaying x-, y-, and z-axis. In example, if you want the x-axis to be twice as large as the y-axis on a 2D plot you should write `pbaspect([2 1 1])`

It works for MATLAB, and I believe it is also available for GNU Octave.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, this in combination with a couple of other tweaks did it for me. Thanks!